# Does Microsoft Store support apps that are made with VB.Net in Winforms? And VB.Net in WPF?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, uwp, windows-store

So, does Microsoft Store support apps that are made with VB.Net in Winforms?

I know the Microsoft Store supports UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps, but I don't know whether the store supports apps that are made with Vb.Net in Winforms.

Also does Microsoft Store support WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) apps that are made with VB.Net?

Comment: hi, yes it does

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7697feef-c85e-453a-8fb5-b6a7ea7f0798/how-can-i-publish-my-winforms-app-into-the-microsoft-store?forum=winforms) page, Winforms apps are not allowed:

> WinForms applications are not allowed at Windows Store, only UWP apps are allowed in the Microsoft Store. UWP provides a more secure ecosystem than other runtimes.

> If you want to publish winform app to windows store, the first step would be to convert your WinForms application to UWP.

MS put out an app to convert Winforms/WPF apps into UWP apps though:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop

For a whole lot more info on that than I could ever post here, here's a good page:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/tips-for-publishing-winforms-wpf-apps-to-microsoft-store

Comment: Another doubt, I found a way to convert Legacy installer to APPX modern installer, but the app is still made with Winforms in VB.Net. Does Microsoft Store support this one?

Comment: Microsoft has allowed desktop apps into the store for quite some time now. They need to be converted to MSIX but that's primarily an install change, not an app change. (Some features won't work once converted).

Comment: Acording to more recent stuff winforms apps are acceable